# Unable to clear the cache in Cucumber (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, cucumber

I am not able to clear the cache for the specific test case.

Used the "Then I clear all the cookies" in the steps.py file but did not work.

If I can open the test run browser in the incognito mode that would be very helpful.

Comment: Is it possible to provide us with a [Complete Minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?